# How to split String and Integer by space between them? in JAVA

Tags: java, string, split, numbers

```
0 START
1 LOAD 20
2 STORE 200
3 LOAD 0
4 STORE 201
5 STORE 202
6 CMPM 200
7 CJMP 15
8 LOADM 202
9 ADDM 201
10 STORE 202
11 LOADM 201
12 ADD 1
13 STORE 201
14 JMP 6
15 LOADM 202
16 DISP
17 HALT
```

I want to split this file by instructions and values like String = "LOAD" int = 20 and remove line numbers.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Is the content in a text file of you have them as `List` ??

Comment: Are you interested in taking the line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to read this file line by line as described for example here
[How can I read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-can-i-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

then for each line you need to do smth. like

```
String[] split = line.split("\\s+");
```

in split array you will have your values for example
{"2", "STORE", "200"}

just parse or perform `Integer.valueOf()` for those that are actually numbers.

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but I'd probably use `"\\s+"` instead of `" "` in case there are multiple spaces or tabs between elements on the line.

Comment: I think because someone is waiting for complete solution:)

Comment: That's certainly possible.